# TikTok Logo in Header not lining up with name

Tags: css, tiktok

my TikTok logo doesn't show up in the header and it's not lining up with Name. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: screenshot]

HTML :

```
 <div class="header">
    <h2 class="name">Name</h2>
    <a class="social-icon-header" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@xxx" target="_blank">
        <img class="tiktok" src="images/TikTok-Icon-Logo.wine.svg">
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.name {
font-size: 250%;
padding-top: 1%; 
 }


/* Social Icon */
.tiktok {
  width: 4em;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using conflicting float and position relative. Trying removing both of those in the tiktock element. and Trying flex on parent container with align-items.

```css
.header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.name {
    font-size: 250%;
}

/* Social Icon */
.tiktok {
    width: 4em;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Brent! Instead of using gap:10px in the header, is there a way to float the TikTok logo to the right? I tried float: right but it didn't do anything.

Comment: of course, use the justify-content attribute instead of gap. and set it to space-between. That should get it for you. I edited the code for you above.